# jQuery change input button value attribute text after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem with my jQuery code on a Website. 
Website: [LastDeath](http://www.lastdeath.de/docs)
I want what the title says, to change the value text in an input button(Send Button). 
I've already Googled and tested some code snippets from other questions, but it doesn't fix my problem. So I asking U guys! :)

If u open the console(in chrome #chromelover) go to sources, js, jq-main.js 
you can see the current code snippet(MESSAGE FORM) for the input button, test.. do whatever you want with it and I would appreciate a comment.

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: you should first  add jquery in your website. always check the developer console

Comment: Yup -- you have $ functions but $ never gets defined. You haven't loaded jquery, whether from your own site or from a CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:
Load jquery first using:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I would start with:

```
$(document).ready() ...
```

As I've never seen `$().ready()`. 
I guess it's what's breaking your code.

I don't understand your idea of changing the text on the button as it is the submit button and the page would be reloaded. In case you want to submit using an AJAX request later, you may want to use preventDefault (https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent page reload.

Comment: A good answer! Thanks man! I Really learned from this one! :))  BTW:  What does the SHA Encryption and the crossorigin="anonymous"? + is there a good place to learn more attributes like these?

Comment: this is just how jquery's website suggest to load their code using a cdn, I don't have a lot of extra information for this :) sorry.

Comment: I've updated it now, so it works! What I have done: Downloaded jQuery from the official page, linked it into my head section and fixed the js code with the following --> $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeBtnValue").click(function() {
            $("#changeBtnValue").val('Thank You!');
        });
    }); .............. THANKS TO ALL HELP!